# Errors in parallel processing with doParallel and the caret package

Tags: r, r-caret, doparallel

I'm running R in an ubuntu LXC container sitting on a server with 32 cores. I'm running a parallel random forest model using the caret package, using a varying number of cores:

```
cl = makeCluster(c(rep("localhost",cores)), outfile = "")
registerDoParallel(cl,cores = cores)

rf_train <- train(gt~.,data=training,
              method='parRF', tuneGrid = data.frame(mtry = 7), na.action = na.omit,
              trControl=trainControl(method='repeatedcv',number=10,
                                     classProbs = TRUE, allowParallel = TRUE)
          )               
stopCluster(cl)
```

When I use `cores <- 1` it runs in serial with no error.

When I use `cores <- 2`, I get no error until I run `stopCluster(cl)`, at which point I get:

```
Warning message:
executing %dopar% sequentially: no parallel backend registered 
Warning message:
executing %dopar% sequentially: no parallel backend registered
```

(Note this is after the process already completed successfully, in parallel, as confirmed by `top`.)

If I use `cores <- 4` or more, in addition to the above warning repeated for each core when I stop the cluster, I also get
`Error in unserialize(socklist[[n]]) : error reading from connection`
before the calculation completes.

This behavior is the same whether I run the calculation in Rstudio Server, or in the console. I have this code from one of my colleagues who was able to run this calculation previously using all 32 cores with no errors. I thought that maybe Rstudio Server was leaking memory, but I can't find evidence of that. (Running `rm()` and `gc()` do not help either).

Any idea what could be causing these errors?